# Bind both lvalues and rvalues to variadic class template parameter

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, c++-concepts

I have a class template that take a variadic number of template arguments. The class has some functions that take arguments corresponding to the class's template parameters. I would like these functions to bind to both lvalues and rvalues. How can I achieve this?

```cpp
template<class ...C>
class Graph {
public:
    Graph(C &...Context); // <- Only lvalues
    Graph(C &&...Context); // <- Only rvalues
    Graph(auto &&...Context); // <- Both lvalues and rvalues, but does not enforce that the types correspond to ...C
};
```

It doesn't seem to be possible to create a `concept` inside the class. Can I create a concept outside the class and pass both the class template pack and the function template pack and verify them in some way? Or can I can add a `requires` clause to the function that can solve it?

I have found some similar questions, but they are quite old, so there are no answers using `concept`s.

Comment: Is the end goal here to copy lvalues and move rvalues? In that case simply taking all parameters by value can many times be a valid option that simplifies your code. The only loss with that approach AFAIK is that you sometimes get an extra move operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is

```cpp
template<class... C>
class Graph {
public:
    template<class... Ts>
    requires (std::same_as<Ts&, C&> and ...)
    Graph(Ts&&... Context);
};
```

This exploits reference collapsing rules for concision.

If you want, you can write a concept for this (here written out in full):

```cpp
template<class T, class U>
concept same_as_or_lvalue_reference_to = std::same_as<T, U> or std::same_as<T, U&>;

template<class... C>
class Graph {
public:
    Graph(same_as_or_lvalue_reference_to<C> auto&&... Context);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I cannot get the `concept` solution to work: `wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)`.

Comment: The `requires` solution is very nice, but it does not work with `const`: `Graph<const int>(42);`.

Comment: Fixed the concept, was missing an `auto`. You can fix it for const by using `std::remove_const_t` and `std::remove_cvref_t` (not as elegant, though).

Answer (score 4):

Concept [`std::constructible_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/constructible_from) might help:

```
template <class... C>
class Graph {
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    requires((std::constructible_from<C, Ts> && ...))
    Graph(Ts&&...);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GvnT1soxM)

or more strict [`std::convertible_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to)

```
template <class... C>
class Graph {
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    requires((std::convertible_to<Ts, C> && ...))
    Graph(Ts&&...);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vn51EKEvf)

or [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as):

```
template <class... C>
class Graph {
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    requires(((std::same_as<Ts&&, C&&>
               || (std::same_as<Ts&&, C&> /*&& !std::is_rvalue_reference_v<C>*/))
            && ...))
    Graph(Ts&&...);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o4orWejPW)

Comment: Thanks. Is the `&&` in `Ts&&` needed? Also, this allows types that can be created from each other. For example, `struct A { int i; }; Graph<A>(42);` would be allowed. How can I make it stricter?

Comment: Extra `&&` removed, added another concept more restrictive.(even more restrictive would be with [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as))

Comment: Could you give an example with `same_as` as well? Just exchanging `constructible_from` with `same_as` does not work.

Comment: `same_as` version added. Unsure if you want to accept rvalue when `C` contains (l/rvalue) reference...

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to it to work exactly like `f(auto &&...)`, just with a constraint on the types allowed by `auto`. The `same_as` version does not seem to work correctly with `const` and `volatile` arguments: https://godbolt.org/z/acq6EhsfW

Comment: [`std::remove_cv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) might help. still unsure of exact requirement for the "edge cases" (`Graph<const int>` vs `Graph<int>` vs `Graph<int&&>` vs ...).

Comment: Yes, I don't have a use case for things like `Graph<const int>` or `Graph<int&&>`, so I think we can just assume that the template arguments will be without references or qualifiers. Would `std::same_as<C, std::decay_t<Ts>>` be a good solution?

Comment: Might be, unless you want `Graph<int[42]>` (array) or `Graph<void ()>` (function).